# Python strings and if statements

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I am having trouble with my Python code. The question that I am supposed to write a program for is below as well as my code. My code works fine in Wing IDE when I run it with different input values for steps, however when I submit it to the system which checks my code I get errors as shown below. Thanks in advance for any help. My code is below.

```
def activity_level_from_steps(steps):
   """Takes an amount of steps and returns the level of exercise it equals"""
    steps = int(steps)
    if steps < 1:
        level = 'alive?'
    elif steps >= 1 and steps < 5000:
        level = 'sedentary'
    elif steps >= 5000 and steps < 7500:
        level = 'very low'
    elif steps >= 7500 and steps < 10000:
        level = 'low'
    elif steps >= 10000 and steps < 12500:
        level = 'active'
    else:
        level = 'very active'

    return level
```

The question I am required to solve

[image]

The error that the system which checks my code gives me

[image]

Comment: Note that you can use e.g. `elif 1 <= steps < 5000:` to simplify the code, which also has the advantage of keeping the comparisons in the same direction. Please give the question and output in text format, as part of an actual [mcve].

Comment: your code is wrong index you shuould put space after (def)  please edit it

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to indent your function body properly, since indentation is important (tm) in Python.

Secondly, you have indented the `return` statement at the same level as your `else`. That will mean that the return is only invoked when the `else` clause is executed. Since a function that doesn't return anything returns `None` by default, your function is shown as returning `None` for all other cases.

```
def activity_level_from_steps(steps):
    """Takes an amount of steps and returns the level of exercise it equals"""
    steps = int(steps)

    if steps < 1:
        level = 'alive?'
    elif steps >= 1 and steps < 5000:
        level = 'sedentary'
    elif steps >= 5000 and steps < 7500:
        level = 'very low'
    elif steps >= 7500 and steps < 10000:
        level = 'low'
    elif steps >= 10000 and steps < 12500:
        level = 'active'
    else:
        level = 'very active'

    return level
```

This can also be simplified, since each elif will only need to check the next step in your activity stair:

```
    if steps < 1:
        level = 'alive?'
    elif steps < 5000:
        level = 'sedentary'
    elif steps < 7500:
        level = 'very low'
    elif steps < 10000:
        level = 'low'
    elif steps < 12500:
        level = 'active'
    else:
        level = 'very active'
```

Comment: I see what youre saying and it makes sense. Where should my return line be indented? Do I indent it on the same level as my def ?

Comment: You indent it at the same level as the main function body, as I've done in my example above. If you had indented it as the same level as `def`, it would not belong to the function, but the scope outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

MatsLindh has you covered, but as a general remark on style and readability, both for being more DRY and for separating settings and logic, you might consider a pattern like this:

```
step_levels = [
    (1, 'alive?'),
    (5000, 'sedentary'),
    (7500, 'very low'),
    (10000, 'low'),
    (12500, 'active'),
    (None, 'very active'),
]

def activity_level_from_steps(steps):
    steps = int(steps)
    for step, level in step_levels:
        if steps < step:
            break
    return level
```

Comment: Instead of break, you could just immediately `return level` as this also 'breaks' out of the function

Comment: Right, but then you'll have two return statements, which the exercise forbids. Or you have to pick some artificial last step.

Comment: Ahh wait that's my bad. It would work if you changed step_levels a bit so it went backwards, I think. Also, that `None` is a bug - `activity_level_from_steps(10**10)` raises a TypeError.